# Activar el evento de DoubleClick de un datagridview desde código C#

Tags: c#, datagrid

Requiero poder llamar el evento DoubleClick de un datagrid desde código, **NO quiero decir crear el evento**, sino llamarlo. el caso es que requiero enviar un dato desde el frm1 al frm2, con ese dato se llena un datagrid, despues quiero que se ejecute lo que esta en el evento DoubleClick  del datagrid.

```
        if (directo == true)
        {
            cmbFiltro.SelectedIndex = 0;
            txtDato.Text = numeroBoleta;
            btnBuscar.PerformClick();
            //Hacer aqui lo que esta en el dgPDF_CellDoubleClick
        }


private void dgPDF_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            File.Delete(server);
        }
        catch (Exception) { //HACE NADA}

        server = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"..\..");
        server = server + dgPDF.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + ".pdf";
        byte[] documento = null;
        documento = (byte[])dgPDF.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value;
        File.WriteAllBytes(server, documento);
        axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(server);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adicionalmente a la respuesta de Juan Salvador, una solución seria que extraigas el código del evento `CellDoubleClick` en un `Método` y así la podrás ejecutar sin depender de la acción del `evento`, tu codigo podria quedar de esta manera:

```
    if (directo == true)
    {
        cmbFiltro.SelectedIndex = 0;
        txtDato.Text = numeroBoleta;
        btnBuscar.PerformClick();
        //Hacer aqui lo que esta en el dgPDF_CellDoubleClick
        ManejoDeArchivo();
    }


private void dgPDF_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    ManejoDeArchivo();
}

private static void ManejoDeArchivo()
{
    try
    {
        File.Delete(server);
    }
    catch (Exception) { //HACE NADA}

    server = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"..\..");
    server = server + dgPDF.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + ".pdf";
    byte[] documento = null;
    documento = (byte[])dgPDF.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value;
    File.WriteAllBytes(server, documento);
    axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(server);
}
```

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurren dos opciones sencillas de hacerlo, la primera, en caso de no necesitar del objeto `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` para tu comportamiento, simplemente haces opcional el parámetro en el evento, osea

```
private void dgPDF_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e = null)
{

}
```

Y luego simplemente lo llamas pasando de parámetro tu `DataGridView`

```
dgPDF_CellDoubleClick(dataGridView1);
```

---

El otro caso, en caso de ser necesario enviarle una fila y columna específicas para ejecutar el evento, podes crear una instancia de `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` usando el constructor [DataGridViewCellEventArgs(Int32, Int32)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Con este ejemplo, lo llamarías de la siguiente manera

```
DataGridViewCellEventArgs Argumentos = new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(0, 15);
dgPDF_CellDoubleClick(dataGridView1,Argumentos);
```

En este ejemplo, el evento se ejecutaría como si se hubiese clickeado en la columna 0, fila 15.